# Discord Bot that can respond to DMs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a simple bot:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
  ],
});
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; // Ignore messages from bots
  message.channel.send('Hello');
});

// login code here
```

I want the bot to respond with "hello" to every DM it receives. Right now, it only successfully responds with "hello" to any message in the server it is on.

How can I do this?
I have the "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" permission toggled in my settings page, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a DM-only bot, you can check the [`channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=type) and ignore anything that's not a DM. You can use the `ChannelType.DM` enum in discord.js v14.

DM channels can be uncached, so you'll also need to add the `Channel` partials:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
  ],
  partials: [Discord.Partials.Channel],
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.channel.type !== ChannelType.DM || message.author.bot) 
    return;

  message.channel.send('Hello');
});
```

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is `messageCreate` is not firing when I send the bot a DM.

Comment: Oh, I see. That was one of the problems. I've just updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: @Foobar Did the `Channel` partials fix this issue?